# Parameters estimation (fit) sensitivity

Tags: partial-derivative, parameter-estimation

I have a linear fit estimation of the following type: ***y=ax+b*** I would like to test how much a mismatch in ***a*** and ***b*** affects the accuracy of ***y***? should I use partial derivative or some other method?

Comment: consider some perturbation analysis on $a,b$

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit about that?